# How to show all lines in nano linux

Tags: command-line, nano

I have a VPS with Ubuntu running on it. I have a text file I opened with nano. However there are too many lines there and only the first 20 or so lines get displayed. After those 20 lines is this:

[image]

How do I make it display the rest? I can jump to some line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>, but I'd rather have the whole file displayed so I could scroll my way through it.

Comment: Use the <up> and <down> arrow keys - it's magic & scrolls   (nano is not my favorite editor, but you chose it)

Comment: @guiverc Do you mean Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down or simply Up and Down? Which editor would you recommend?

Comment: I don't use `nano` , I just opened a term & `nano jounr..` (a big text file) and arrow keys scrolled the text file up & down for me (somewhat jerky, it scrolled a few lines each time (not the one line I like with `view` or `vim` - but I've been using `vi` since the end 80s so anything else wouldn't feel like home)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for the answer. Currently all command line editors feel foreign to me and I'm constantly afraid to screw things up. But I'll check out `vim`.

Comment: Note, if you only want to *read* the file, use `less` or `more`

Comment: `vim` is an editor, which is why I mentioned `view` (read only version of vim).  `vim` is not what I'd call user friendly. Part of why I used `vi` was it worked if your terminal didn't have working arrow keys (which was common early-mid 1980s before terminals were replaced by cheap pc-clones).  vi/vim is keyboard efficient and most people today, accustomed to mice/gui wouldn't probably find it a good fit.

Comment: "Currently all command line editors feel foreign to me and I'm constantly afraid to screw things up." – Then in my opinion stay with `nano` or maybe `mcedit`, and forget the `vim` recommendation.

Comment: "How do I make it display the rest?" – If the file is just a little bit longer than what's displayed, you can make the window taller. If the file is much longer, you won't be able to fit it at once, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Terminal window is small, large text will certainly get truncated. You can either use <kbd>↑</kbd> (upwards arrow) / <kbd>↓</kbd> (downwards arrow) keys or your mouse scroll wheel to scroll up or down to view the truncated part.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> toggles the display of the two last lines that display the functions of the hotkeys. Turning this off will help preserving some screen real estate for text.